# Python. Django. An Error "No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form" with UpdateView class

Tags: python, django

I new with Django. I hope you could help me with this error "No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form".
I've read several questions on stackoverflow, but there was problems with absence of "save()" in function in views.py, or absence of method "post", or absence of "csrf_token" in HTML. But I use UpdateView class and method "post" and "csrf_token" are included in HTML file. I have no any idea what the problem is.

This is a  blog-service with the function of adding/ updating/ deleting cities and trains. I use CreateView/ UpdateView/ DeleteView classes. Information regarding to cities and trains is stored in linked tables. All classes in the "cities" app (views.py) work without problems, the same classes copied to the "trains" app don't work for creating and changing data through the form on the site. It raise an error right on the page: "Not a single file was sent. Check the encoding type of the form".

At the same time, the deletion works correctly on the site. And create/ update/ delete work correctly through the admin panel.

The corresponding models and forms have been created for the "trains" app. Both apps are registered in settings.py.

Please tell me: where could be the problem? Thank you in advance.

views.py

```
class TrainListView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 4
    model = Train
    template_name = "trains/trains.html"


class TrainDetailView(DetailView):
    queryset = Train.objects.all()
    template_name = "trains/detail.html"


class TrainCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Train
    form_class = TrainForm
    template_name = "trains/create.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("trains:trains")
    success_message = "Train has been created"


class TrainUpdateView(SuccessMessageMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Train
    form_class = TrainForm
    template_name = "trains/update.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("trains:trains")
    success_message = "Train has been updated"


class TrainDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Train
    template_name = "trains/delete.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("trains:trains")

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        messages.success(request, "Train has been deleted")
        return self.post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

forms.py

```
class TrainForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label="Train",
                           widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                               "class": "form-control",
                               "placeholder": "Input train name"
                           }))

    travel_time = forms.ImageField(label="Travel time",
                                   widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
                                       "class": "form-control",
                                       "placeholder": "Input travel time"
                                   }))

    departure_city = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Departure city",
                                            queryset=City.objects.all(),
                                            widget=forms.Select(attrs={
                                                "class": "form-control",
                                            }))

    destination_city = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Destination city",
                                              queryset=City.objects.all(),
                                              widget=forms.Select(attrs={
                                                  "class": "form-control",
                                              }))

    class Meta:
        model = Train
        fields = "__all__"
```

models.py

```
class Train(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name="Train")
    travel_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name="Travel time")

    departure_city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                       related_name="departure_city_set",
                                       verbose_name="Departure city"
                                       )
    destination_city = models.ForeignKey("cities.City", on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                         related_name="destination_city_set",
                                         verbose_name="Destination city"
                                         )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Train {self.name} from {self.departure_city} to {self.destination_city}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Train"
        verbose_name_plural = "Trains"
        ordering = ["name"]

    def clean(self):
        if self.departure_city == self.destination_city:
            raise ValidationError("Departure city and destination city can't be the same")
        qs = Train.objects.filter(departure_city=self.departure_city,
                                  destination_city=self.destination_city,
                                  travel_time=self.travel_time,
                                  ).exclude(pk=self.id)

        if qs.exists():
            raise ValidationError("Change travel time")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.clean()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

trains/update.html

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% block title %} Train update {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Train update</h1>

    {% include "main/form.html" with button="Update" %}

{% endblock %}
```

main/form.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form action="{{action}}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">{{ button }}</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

urls.py

```
app_name = "trains"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TrainListView.as_view(), name="trains"),
    path('<int:pk>/', TrainDetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
    path('create/', TrainCreateView.as_view(), name="create"),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', TrainUpdateView.as_view(), name="update"),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/', TrainDeleteView.as_view(), name="delete"),
              ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `forms.py`, is `travel_time` supposed to be an ImageField? That seems like the reason that it would be expecting a file to be submitted.

Comment: Yes, thank you that was the problem - wrong tipe of  input was for ImageField.